# Is there a way I can run scripts in an opendaylight controller without using the GUI?

Tags: opendaylight

I have a Mininet network and have connected it to an ODL controller. I want to add flows in the controller (and not through Mininet) to be able to get pings and monitor traffic in the network.

What I've seen online, suggested that I connect to the GUI of the controller and create flows there, but I want to know if I can implement/modify flows in the controller itself. I want to run an ODL script without using the GUI. Any help will be much appreciated (links, suggestions etc.).

(I am using ODL 16.02)

Can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also new to ODL. It seems the ODL GUI is [no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341871/how-to-add-dlux-to-new-opendaylight-application/52370705#52370705) and the only way to add flows is through RESTCONF. In order to do this, you will need an API testing software. You can use *curl* and I have seen that *Postman* is very popular, but there are [other alternatives](https://testfully.io/blog/top-5-postman-alternatives/).

[This link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7tmeIDNHJ0) shows a video where they demonstrate how to configure flows using Postman. I wish there were more information for beginners about how to configure flows and features, since I am also having problems understanding how to use ODL.